# Unable to get my development server to work

Tags: wampserver

I installed Wampserver (including the 2 Visual C++ service packs).  I placed my tutorial files in the c:\wamp\www\ directory.

On the service tray, I'll go to "localhost" & "Your Projects" & I'll try to open an .html document that submits a form to a .php document.

I get a "Server Not Found" error.

Thank you in advance!

It worked for me several years ago.  The tutorial files are in an O'Reilly book ("Missing Manual")

Comment: What you see when opening browser at `http://localhost` ?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP uses Apache. Go to your start menu, and search for WAMP, which should display a WAMP icon in your hidden icons section of your windows task bar. Just click on it, and click start all services, and bam!

Check out this post on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/a/980974